# Storing ints within multiple arrays in C

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, if-statement, char

Down below is a function where it stores 5 of users X and Y. The function is supposed to print all the integers the user has inputted in the past. Player X's inputs are stored in `X_users_inputs` and Player Y's inputs are stored in `O_user_inputs`. The value of `k` is meant to shift from one user to another after every single input.

The if and else statements are not working properly. I do not know how to fix it.

```
int main(void) {
  int input = 0, k = 0;
  char playerSelect[][2] = {"1", "2"};
  int X_users_inputs[10] = {0};
  int O_user_inputs[10] = {0};
  for (int i = 1; i <= 11; i++) {
    printf("\nPlayer %s input: ", playerSelect[k]);

    scanf("%d", &input);
    if (k == 0) {
      X_users_inputs[i - 1] = input;
      for (int l = 0; l < i; l++) {
        printf("X user %d\n", X_users_inputs[l]);
      }
    } else {
      O_user_inputs[i - 1] = input;
      for (int s = 0; s < i; s++) {
        printf("Y user %d\n", X_users_inputs[s]);
      }
    }
    k = ((i % 2 == 0) ? 0 : 1);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
User X input: 1
X inputs 1

User O input: 2
Y inputs 1
Y inputs 0

User X input: 3
X inputs 1
X inputs 0
X inputs 3
```

Expected Output:

```
User X input: 1
X inputs 1

User O input: 2
Y inputs 2

User X input: 3
X inputs 1
X inputs 3
```

Comment: The code and the output do not match. Please correct that to make it a bit easier to follow. Make sure to run the exact code that you post and use the exact output from that.

Comment: Don't need such fancy ping pong code. For each iteration just repeat the same code for each user. Then further improve that by factoring the common code into a function and call the function twice in the loop.

Comment: The `Output` of 1 2 and 3 is the actual output of the code. I have tested it multiple times. The expected output was supposed to be the correction of it.

Comment: `User X input` there is nothing in the code that prints such output. So that output can't have come from that exact code.

Comment: Aside: simplify: `k = ((i % 2 == 0) ? 0 : 1);` --> `k = !k` or the like.

Comment: This is a good time to use an `enum { X, Y }` instead of 0, 1. Also `{1, 11}` is 11 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

At least this issue:

```
// printf("Y user %d\n", X_users_inputs[s])
printf("Y user %d\n", O_users_inputs[s])
```